# Как запустить таймер при открытии формы Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Возникла проблема с запуском статического таймера после того как была открыта форма.
Необходимо реализовать:

Если форма открыта но на ней на протяжении двух минут никакие кнопки не нажимаются то выдать предупреждение(понятное дело делается через MessageBox). Далее, если пользователь нажал на какую либо кнопку или на область формы то сбросить таймер до нуля и запустить заново(то есть таким образом контролировать взаемодействие пользователя с формой). Таким образом после каждого нажатия кнопки или области на форме сбрасывать таймер до нуля и запускать заново
У меня же таймер объявлен как статическая переменная(со спецификатором static)
В моем проекте добавлено две Windows-формы. На первой расположена одна кнопка которая после нажатия переключает пользователя на вторую форму но вот после запуска моего кода у меня получаеться следующая ситуация:

После того как я нажимаю на кнопку на первой форме, у меня вместо того чтобы первая форма закрылась, а вторая открылась и запустился таймер получается так что после нажатия на кнопку на первой форме ничего не происходит и вообще после этого даже закрыть первую форму не получается(ни закрыть, ни свернуть, ни раскрыть на весь экран)

Мой код выглядит следующим образом(язык С#)

Файл Form1.cs(Там расположена та самая кнопка которая после нажатия ничего не делает)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Component.Model;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
namespace McDonalds
{
    public partial class Form1: Form 
    {
        public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void OrderBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2(); // Создаем экземпляр формы 2 
            form2.Show(); // После нажатия кнопки выводим ее на экран 
            this.Hide(); // Текущую форму закрываем(прячем от пользователя) 
        }
    } 
}
```

Файл Form2.cs(там где нужно провернуть данную операцию с таймером)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Component.Model;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
namespace McDonalds
{
     public bool buttonClicked = false; // В начале на форме 2 никакие кнопки не нажимаются 
     public static Timer timer = new Timer(); // Вот здесь я оглашаю статическую переменную Timer
     public Form2()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         timer.Interval = 120000; // устанавливаю таймер на 120 000 миллисекунд(2 минуты)
         timer.Enabled = true;
         timer.Start(); // Запускаю таймер 
         while(timer.Interval >= 0)
         {
              timer.Interval--;
              if(!buttonClicked && timer.Interval.Equals(0))
              {
                   MessageBox.Show("You are not active, in time your order will be automatticaly deleted!");
                   timer.Stop();
                   timer.Interval = 60000;
                   timer.Start();
                   while(timer.Interval >= 0)
                   {
                      timer.Interval--;
                      if(!buttonClicked && timer.Interval.Equals(0))
                      {
                          timer.Stop();
                          this.Hide();
                      }
                      else 
                      {
                          timer.Interval = 120000;
                      }
                   }
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Ваше приложение зависает потому что вы всю логику интерфейса заняли своими циклами, а значит отвечать на действия юзера или рисовать окна оно не может

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: Ну а зачем вам эти циклы? Вам надо реагировать ровно прям через 2 минуты?

Comment: А как это исправить? Можно шаблон кода пожалуйста :)

Comment: Вы на вопросы ответьте сначала

Comment: С помощью циклов я контролирую количество времени которое прошло. И да, реагировать нужно ровно через 2 минуты

Comment: Разберитесь сгачала с тем, что таеое таймер и как он работает, вроде просто должно быть. Текущее представление о таймерах а вас не соответствует реальности. Инструкцию любую откройте чтоли, никаких циклов не должно быть вообще. И таймер в вашем случае не должен быть статичесним.

Comment: ну то есть вам надо 1) запустить таймер на 2 минуты 2) перезапускайть его каждый раз, когда юзер что то сделает 3) если таймер сработал - значит юзер 2 минуты без активности сидит. Подумайте над такой логикой.

Comment: А можно показать пожалуйста шаблон, а то туго доходит

Comment: _Мне по заданию нужно создать статическую переменную типа Тimer_ - почему статическую, вы точно ничего не перепутали? И не переменную, а поле. Вот документация https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer

Comment: Вполне вероятно тебе может помочь ответ из другого поста - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963135/wpf-inactivity-and-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простейшая форма с таймером и кнопкой.

Ждет 5 секунд и если кнопку не нажимали - выдает сообщение.
Если кнопку нажимали, то таймер просто перезапускается на следующие 5 секунд.

```
class MyFormWithTimer : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public MyFormWithTimer()
    {
        var button = new Button() { Text = "Press me", Width = 150, Height = 100 };
        this.Controls.Add(button);
        button.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        };

        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("You are idle!");
        };

        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Enabled = true;

        this.FormClosed += (sender, args) => timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: А если кнопок много? Тогда что делать

Comment: К каждой кнопке событие цеплять, очевидно же

Comment: Ну я немного по-другому сделал. Тут другая проблема появилась, а именно: Когда выскочил MessageBox то зафиксировать его появление и запустить таймер когда он открыт  и пока он открыт и если пользователь не нажмет кнопку OK или крестик то закрыть форму. Вот с этим проблема

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, не связанный с изначальным вашим вопросом. А раз другой вопрос - то и задавайте его отдельно

Comment: @aepot Поставил